# What triggers the IE Enhanced Security warning

Tags: jquery, html, security, internet-explorer

Is there a published set of IE enhanced security blocking rules?

Background:  When I try out certain jQuery scripts, I sometimes trigger the IE enhanced security warning - then its a matter of trial and error removing bits of the code until I find the offending part,and see if the jQuery can work without it.  commenting out the code doesn't always work, you have to delete it from your page.

A utility that can pinpoint the blocked part of your html/script would be useful.

EDIT:  I was trying to implement dynamic tooltips using this:

http://www.queness.com/post/92/create-a-simple-cssjavascript-tooltip-with-jquery

Now there is no shortage of other ways of doing tooltips, its finding out what triggers the IE enhanced security warnings that I'm after.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you've found in "...certain jQuery scripts..." that triggered the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this script from a webserver or from a local file?

There is a known issue with  IE enhanced security warnings on local files.  Just in case thats you're issue, there is a fix which consists of placing the following between the opening  tag.

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```